# set UItextfield.text from NSObject class

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I need to set a string to a textfield from a `NSObject` class.Is it possible without passing it to `view controller` class.
Is it possible by importing `view controller.h` into the `NSObject` and then by simply using

```
UItextfield.text= string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can pass value from NSObject class to UIViewController class. Create and property for string or UITextField and set its value from that NSObject Class.

In UIViewController.h file create property,

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UItextField *theTextField;
```

In UIViewController.m file

```
@synthesize theTextField;
```

In NSObject. Class

```
[uiviewControllerObject.theTextField setText:@"YOUR_TEXT_IN_STRING"];
```

Also their a lots of way to communication between objective classes such as using NSNotificationCenter, delegate, KVO, Objective-C message passing using custom methods. But all are varies depends on situations. But in your scenario property is best way to set text from NSObject class.

Comment: could please tell me how to do it, with an example.

Comment: @sreejith.virgo, friend, if your read and understand correctly my answer then you no need depends on any example. BTW it very hard to find exact short example for You.

Comment: Go through this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html